# How to design an android viewpager

Tags: android

Am just wondering how can I design an activity like in the image below. This pattern is also found when you select to view an app detail in Google play.

Do we use ViewPager for this kind of design?

Links to examples, tutorials will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you want this kind of layout in Tablets or Mobile Devices? In Tablets its Fragments that will do it for you, in mobile devices its not worth so clumsy layout!

Comment: using the fragments we can achieve the layout. if ur app supports only Tablets(above 3.0) we can use directly otherwise we can use the support jar android-support-v4.jar http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: *Fragments* can help you out.

Comment: you can use ListView with custom adapters for vertical scroll and HorizontalScrollView for horizontal scrolling(or ViewPager, depends on what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is it a valid way of doing or not. I prefer doing it entirely using Linear layout.

```
 <!-- parent layout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--     splitting into 2 horizontal  -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

<!--         1st part of horizontal -->
        <LinearLayout 

            android:layout_width="x_value"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
             <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

<!--            include content -->

             </ScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <!--         2nd part of horizontal -->

        <LinearLayout 

            android:layout_width="x_value"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

                    <!--   fixed header part-->
                            <LinearLayout             
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="y_value"        
                            >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <!--   next 2 vertical splits with scrollbar-->

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="y_value"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                 >
                                                <ScrollView
                                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                                                    android:layout_weight="1">
                                                            <LinearLayout             
                                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                            android:layout_height="y_value"
                                                            >
                                                                    <ScrollView
                                                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                                                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                                                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                                                        <!--  include content -->

                                                                     </ScrollView>      


                                                            </LinearLayout>

                                                            <LinearLayout             
                                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                            android:layout_height="y_value"
                                                            >

                                                             </LinearLayout>
                                                 </ScrollView>

                            </LinearLayout>

             </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


I hope this would give some idea.
```